# How can I make sure a TCP server will always be running on a VM (google cloud)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, tcp, virtual-machine

I am using VM from Google Cloud Platform running Windows Server 2019. I currently have a simple TCP server(node.js) that receives data and then POSTs it to my firestore database using Axios. It is important for me that the server doesn't crash and in the case that it does, it can restart and "stay alive". How can I accomplish this?

New to VM and TCP servers. Just made a simple

**TCP**

```
const net = require('net');
const axios = require('axios')
const chalk = require('chalk');

const server = net.createServer(conn => {

    console.log(chalk.green('new client'));

      conn.on('data', data => {
        // let add = conn.address()
      
        console.log(data)
    
        if(data.length > 0){

            axios.post('https://abc', {
            data: data
          })
          .then(response => {
    
        conn.write('ACK');

          }).catch(err =>{
        conn.write('ERR', err)
                console.log(err)
          })
        }
    });

    conn.on('end', () => {
        console.log(chalk.red('client left '));
    console.log(chalk.white.bold('----------------------------------'));
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Usually a separate process is responsible to act as a “watchdog” and ensure restarts and notifications on critical failures.

Comment: Are there any suggested processes to monitor a simple TCP server?

Comment: Search for "node.js restart crashed process", etc. Note that crash/not-running are different from broken-code-not-responding / network-down / etc. The latter require appropriate detection of these cases, beyond just a basic process monitor, which are then fed back into some action (or alert) to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Running a node.js application on Windows Server has several challenges.

1. Installation and setup of a monitoring application that detects that the node.js application has failed and restarts the application. An example product that provides this ability is `node-windows`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-windows

This is an example and not a recommendation for any specific product.

2. The monitoring application must be installed and set up as a Windows service so that the monitoring application restarts automatically. The application `node-windows` also provides this capability.
3. Install the application files outside of your user environment. This means creating a directory with the correct ownership and rights so that the Windows service can access the files.

This article written by Charan Tej might help to understand the details:

[Node Windows Service for Running Node.js Application](http://bestirtech.com/blog/2019/02/node-windows-service-node-js-app/)

Comment: Before you replied I started using PM2: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/ would love your opinion on that if you are aware of it. If I were to switch OS on my VM what would you recommend?

Comment: @Yewla PM2 is a well known package. I used pm2-windows-service to set up the service part. I used this article written by Adam Tuttle to get started last year. https://adamtuttle.codes/blog/2019/node-apps-as-windows-services/